# Why is \lcm not defined as default?

Tags: math-operators

Using only a class (`report` for example) we can use `\gcd`. But `\lcm` is not defined. Why?

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\[  \lcm  \]
\end{document}
```

Why new distributions of TeX Live or MiKTeX don't have this command defined?

Comment: Because it's not LaTeX. For some reason LaTeX (Lamport) does provide `\gcd` but not `\lcm`. As @ryan-reich explains you can define your own math operators or include a package that defines them.

Answer (score 22):

I've often wondered why some symbol or operator doesn't have a name, when it seems to be so common in my papers ("Hom" being the big offender...who doesn't use this?!).  The fact is, however, that there are practically an enormous number and potentially an *infinite* number of mathematical operator names, and as David Carlisle observes in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111815/575), at the time that the basic math package (`amsmath` and its siblings) was written, the number of macro names was a crucial issue, with far tighter constraints than you'd believe in these times.

Another comment on this situation is that neither MikTeX nor TeX Live actually alters the source code of the packages they distribute.  They do provide package managers, binary executables of TeX and various related programs, and possibly scripts to automate them (MikTeX seems to have a download-on-demand feature built into its "tex", for example).  But they don't dig into the packages, because that would violate the [LPPL](http://latex-project.org/lppl/lppl-1-3c.html) under which most of these packages are released.

That said, you might still feel some righteous indignation that they didn't choose *your* favorite operator name (again, name me a field of math that doesn't use "Hom"!).  The fact is that your symbol isn't as important as you think it is (answer: calculus.  Most of the pre-defined symbols are weighted heavily towards math up to the level of first- or second-year undergraduate education).

Finally, there's no big problem with space these days, and you can simply write

```
% \usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}
```

at the beginning of your document.  In fact, when you get enough of these you'll probably do as I have, and collect all such definitions into a file called, say, "mymath.tex", which you include with `\input{mymath}` all the time, and slowly forget what is and is not actually standard.

Comment: the origin of the "basic" list of operator names was knuth's need for them in his books in the series "the art of computer programming"; these are defined in `plain.tex`, and a few more in `manmac.tex`.  the additions defined in `amsopn.sty` were those most frequently called for in publications of the american math society.  actually, `\hom` (lowercase) *is* included in the `amsopn` collection; i'm not knowledgeable enough to know the difference between "hom" and "Hom".

Comment: @barbara Oh, you're right.  I'm sure I noticed `\hom` in the past, but probably wanted the capital H and eventually forgot.  One that really *is* missing is `im`, for image (goes with `\ker`, right?)

Comment: as i mentioned, i'm not a mathematician.  (tried; didn't succeed; ended up in linguistics and publishing-related pursuits with a "math flavor".)  so i *do* recognize that `\Im` (imaginary, but a symbol, not an operator name) is not the same as "image", but don't have the notion instilled that "image" and "kernel" are siblings.  i guess i'll have to expand my reading.

Comment: People, nice discussion. I understand and I agree that there are many missing symbols. But my question is based on the fact that `gcd` is there and it is close related with `lcm` as much as `ker` is related with `im`. It is strange since is almost sure that if we use `gcd` we shall use `lcm` also.

Comment: @Sigur And if we use `ker` we will almost certainly use `im`; nonetheless, neither `\lcm` nor `\im` is defined, and `\hom` is defined differently than the convention I learned.  The point is that the symbols in the AMS packages were designed under limitations a long time ago, and are not being redesigned, but that there are many extension packages or commands you can use to get the symbol you want.